# Convert month shortname to month number

Tags: mysql, sql, string-to-datetime

I am searching for a built-in function in **MySQL** for getting **Month Number** for given **Month Short Name** like `'Jan','jul',etc.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`STR_TO_DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function to convert String to Date like this:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('Apr','%b')
```

And use [`MONTH()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month) to get month number from the date like this:

```
SELECT MONTH(STR_TO_DATE('Apr','%b'))
```

#### See [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9069e/1)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select month(str_to_date('Mar','%b'));
```